# Copying non-contiguous cells from one column to another in Google Sheets with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two columns of checkboxes in a Google Sheets document (`column A` and `column B`, for example sake), and I want to be able to add a function that will look down `column A`, and move any checked boxes into `column B`, while ignoring any rows where the cell in `column A` is blank. I intend to add this function into a drop down menu in in my spreadsheet.

So, as an illustration:

Sheet before running this function:

```
Column A | Column B
=====================
    ✓    |     ☐       
    ✓    |     ☐       
    ☐    |     ☐       
    ☐    |     ✓       

        ---
```

Sheet after running this function:

```
Column A | Column B
=====================
    ☐    |     ✓       
    ☐    |     ✓       
    ☐    |     ☐       
    ☐    |     ✓
```

I've figured out how to check or uncheck whole ranges, so I can clear `column A` easy enough, but I can't figure out what to do to change those specific cells in `column B` where `column A` is checked first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function runTwo() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0] && vA[i][0]==true) {
      vA[i][0]=false;
      vA[i][1]=true;
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Comment: You rock, this worked perfectly. The only thing I changed was using `getRange` instead of `getDataRange` at the fourth line, to just run it against a specific range in the sheet. Everything is working exactly as it should. Thanks a ton!